# How to emulate a serial port for testing

Tags: .net, serial-port

I neeed to write a device emulator for testing purposes that connects through a serial port. I know there are some apps out there to do this, but that doesn't really help my curiousity, lol. I would like to know how in .net I could write a sniffer to watch the traffic in and out on a serial port. I'm also interested in what suggestions anyone has to accomplish my testing, but I want something in .net and not a 3rd party download.

Comment: What exactly do you want to write - device emulator or port sniffer? These are different things.

Comment: Both actually. I'm curious about both and have seperate uses for both.

Comment: There are many ready-to use COM port sniffers, for example, PortMon. Why do you need one more? This should be done in C/C++, most of work in kernel mode. On the other hand, .NET is OK to write device emulator - just use SerialPort class.

Comment: Mostly to know if and how it could be accomplished in .net. I might be missing something on the SerialPort class. My understanding is that it will not let you watch or intercept traffic on a serial port that is open by another application.

Comment: SerialPort can be used only for standard COM port communication, not for sniffing. If you are interesting in a port sniffing, forget about .NET, this task requires low level programming.

Comment: BTW, all this is not related to device emulator - it can be done in any .NET language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always write a virtual serial port in software and connect your application to that port. There is GPL driver source code out there that should give you a head start on how to do it:

http://com0com.sourceforge.net/

I might have to add, writing a virtual device usually involves writing a driver, something you obviously can't do in a managed language.